# Difference between `node /* ... */` and `npx hardhat run /* ... */`

Tags: hardhat

When I run the following commands:

- Terminal 1: `npx hardhat node`
- Terminal 2: `npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network localhost`

I see the blockchain node created on terminal 1 execute things as I'd expect:
[image]

But if I run the following commands:

- Terminal 1: `npx hardhat node` (no changes)
- Terminal 2: `node scripts/sample-script.js --network localhost`

I see no activity on Terminal 1.

So **what's the difference between `node /* ... */` and `npx hardhat run /* ... */`?**

I'm running the standard sample-script.js (pasted below without its original comments):

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");

  await greeter.deployed();

  console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`npx hardhat node` and `npx hardhat run` are both tasks that come by default in hardhat. You can check all defined tasks with the following commands: `npx hardhat` or `npx hardhat help`.

[image]

Here you have that:

- **node:** Starts a JSON-RPC server on top of Hardhat EVM;
- **run:** Runs a user-defined script after compiling the project

You can also create your own tasks. Take a look at the [docs](https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task).